# How do I combine two columns with different formatting?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to produce a table in HTML to contain some code examples in the first column with alternating row colours, with a second column to contain comments.

This is a rough mockup of what I'm going for:

[image: Aim]

And this is what my current code produces:

[image: Current results]

The HTML and the CSS I'm using are these:

```css
    table.codepack {
      margin-left: 250px;
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    col.vba {
      border-left: 1px solid #8bd5e6;
      font-family: Courier, monospace;
      font-size: small:
      padding: 0;
      width: 70%;
    }
    
    col.vba tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #b8eaef;
    }
    
    col.vba tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #d0eef4;
    }
        
    col.notes {
      width: 30%;
    }
    
    div.comment {
      margin: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #e6b000;
      border-radius: 6px;
      background-color: #fff9e6;
      font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: small;
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<table class=codepack>
  <col class="vba"><col class="notes">
  <tr>
    <td>  Sub Newcode</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  IF RandomVar = True then</td>
    <td><div class="comment">This is a comment.</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  &nbsp;&nbsp;Random2 = Blue</td>
    <td><div class="comment">This is a comment.</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  ELSE</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Some bits are working - the Comment `<div>`, for instance - but none of the things I've tried for the first column have given a good result. I've tried declaring `.vba` both on its own and specific to both `tr` and `td`, but to no avail. I've also tried various versions of declaring the `nth-child` styles, again with no more success.

Any idea how I could achieve that result? I'm not wedded to using tables - indeed, I'd prefer not to - but I couldn't think of a better way offhand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I could think of do it was to not worry about coloring within specific columns, and then just make sure that the second cell in each row was the same color using :nth-of-type.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #b8eaef;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #d0eef4;
}

td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

[CodePen Here.](https://codepen.io/LukasFauset/pen/QGvYLJ)

Answer (score 1):

There are a million other ways for you to do this, without tables. (Bootstrap for example, have div.row instead of a tr), but if you pick your current code, you need to either add a class to each td, or work with pseudoselectors of the td.

```css
table.codepack {
      margin-left: 250px;
      width: 80%;
    }

    col.vba {
      border-left: 1px solid #8bd5e6;
      font-family: Courier, monospace;
      font-size: small:
      padding: 0;
      width: 70%;
    }
    
    col.vba tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #b8eaef;
    }
    
    col.vba tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #d0eef4;
    }
        
    col.notes {
      width: 30%;
    }
    
    div.comment {
      margin: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #e6b000;
      border-radius: 6px;
      background-color: #fff9e6;
      font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: small;
      font-style: italic;
    }


td:first-child {background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<table class="codepack" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <col class="vba"><col class="notes">
  <tr>
    <td>  Sub Newcode</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  IF RandomVar = True then</td>
    <td><div class="comment">This is a comment.</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  &nbsp;&nbsp;Random2 = Blue</td>
    <td><div class="comment">This is a comment.</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  ELSE</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Note that I added cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0" to the , and the last bit of css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use display:flex

check the following snippet

```css
.code {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-code {
  display: flex;
}
.comment {
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e6b000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #fff9e6;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  font-style: italic;
}
.text {
  border: 1px solid #8bd5e6;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="code">
    <code class="text">Sub Newcode</code>

    <div class="sub-code">
      <code class="text">IF RandomVar = True then </code>
      <div class="comment">This is a comment.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-code">
      <code class="text"> Random2 = Blue </code>
      <div class="comment">This is a comment.</div>
    </div>
    <code class="text">ELSE</code>


  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

`col` is fine for setting widths and that's all. You can't select `td` as if they were owned by a certain col or had it as a parent. That's not the case. You have to style the nth col a certain way and the nth cells in a related way, in 2 different rules.

`tr` don't have `col` element as a parent (but as a sibling... of all existing `col`s so you can't do anything useful with that in CSS (`*`)) so you should remove col.vba from selectors related to tr.
And you can select these cells in the 1st column of each odd row with `:nth-child(odd)` for example and style their `td:first-child` cells.
(`*`) `col + tr` would select something: tr following a col element, but that's all of them here, so nothing more useful than a simple `tr` :)

Here I removed anything related to col and styled (cells in their repective) "columns" with `td:first-child` and `td:last-child` (also works with `td:nth-child(2)` and useful if you've 3+ columns)

```css
    table.codepack {
      margin-left: 250px;
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    td:first-child {
      border-left: 1px solid #8bd5e6;
      font-family: Courier, monospace;
      font-size: small:
      padding: 0;
      width: 70%;
    }
    
    td:last-child {
      width: 30%;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(odd) td:first-child {
      background-color: #b8eaef;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child {
      background-color: #d0eef4;
    }
        
    div.comment {
      margin: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #e6b000;
      border-radius: 6px;
      background-color: #fff9e6;
      font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: small;
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<table class=codepack>
  <col class="vba"><col class="notes">
  <tr>
    <td>  Sub Newcode</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  IF RandomVar = True then</td>
    <td><div class="comment">This is a comment.</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  &nbsp;&nbsp;Random2 = Blue</td>
    <td><div class="comment">This is a comment.</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  ELSE</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

EDIT: if you do want widths being 70%/30% whatever the lengths of content in columns, you should use the *other* [table layout algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) (MDN), the one that does what the author want and not what content may modify by its length:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Ah, right - W3C make it sound as though col is used for setting styles. Pity, that would have been useful. Cheers, I'll try this when I get in to work.

Comment: Did you mean W3schools? [They're unrelated](https://twitter.com/w3c/status/800647059305091072) ^_^ (and [W3schools used to have "some" errors to the point W3Fools was created](https://web.archive.org/web/20110309192636/http://w3fools.com/) - long list of errors was long). Well `col` can be used but "by itself", not as a parent selector because it isn't a parent in HTML (if you aren't generating those tables yourself, I wonder which WYSIWYG create them? I use thead>th for that)